# Call Web API from MVC Controller Hanging Up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, task

I've tried many different approaches for the past couple of hours, but my method call is hanging up the thread.

Here is my Web API code, which works fine when making AJAX call from the MVC client, but I'm trying to test calling from the server:

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Below is my MVC controller code and model code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestApi()
{
    try
    {
        var result = await VoipModels.GetValues();

        return MVCUtils.JsonContent(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return MVCUtils.HandleError(ex);
    }
}
...
    public static async Task<string[]> GetValues()
    {
        string[] result = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44305/api/");

            //THIS IS THE LINE THAT HANGS UP - I'VE TRIED MANY VARIATIONS
            var response = await client.GetAsync("values", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string[]>();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I've used this format successfully when calling a separate, 3rd party API. I've run out of examples to try from my couple of hours of Googling.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why spin up another whole thread to do work when either the calling code could hit the API directly or the local code could call the API code without using HTTP?

Comment: Did you check http://localhost:44305/api/values when running this code?

Comment: This looks incorrect, as you shouldn't design the server to make a request to itself. It's not very efficient.

Comment: I'm working on a proof-of-concept. The idea is to split our main app into functional areas that can be published independently and provide different hosting scenarios.

Comment: make sure your API is up in IIS and reachable. use  `try catch` block in controller to identify the issue. I do worked in project solution with project (Web, Model, API, Data) Here API is used for both web and mobile app interaction with server. +1 for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Check your port number.** Based on your code, you have "hard coded" the port `"http://localhost:44305/api/"` which may likely be incorrect, you should convert that to grab it from the host 
   configuration instead.
2. **Check your local machine's firewall.** Make sure that your local machine's firewall is allowing connections to the port assigned.
3. **Check your protocol.** Ensure that you are using http or https appropriately in your request URL.

As a special note, there are very rare cases / exception cases that you would want to have a web API server call itself. Doing so, is rather inefficient design as it will consume resources for no gain (such a generating request and response).

Comment: Well, the port number was right, but your reply made me inspect the address again. I realized I had forgotten to make it "https". Add the secure protocol fixed the problem (banged my head over a single letter - lol). 

Additionally, the idea is to separate our rather large application into functional areas that can be published independently and open us up to different hosting scenarios. In this particular case, we want to separate out our VOIP processes (Twilio) and interface them with our main app via API calls.